# Can I use solrj driver 8.5.0 in my indexer client without logging in log4j2?

Tags: java, solr, log4j, log4j2, solrj

We are upgrading solr to 8.5.2 from an old solr.

We have a client indexer and some websites that will need to upgrade the solrj driver in order to communicate with the server.
The new solrj driver (8.5.0) comes with dependencies for log4j2, but we are still using the old log4j.

My question is, are we forced to change the indexer and the sites that query the solr server in order to use log4j2 or can we continue to use the login system we already have in place?
I understand that the server itself will log using log4j2, but i am confused about the clients.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the maven for dependency management then you need not have to bother about the solrj dependencies.

But you are managing the libs or dependencies at your own. Then you need to add the dependent libs in for the solrj lib.